Filtering out duplicates within a CTE
The data in this cte looks like this:
h_pit as (
    select
        *
    from "h_pit"
)

id       hash_key1.       hash_key2         business_key               date             value
1        12233               234                     123               12-01-2000        5
3        33333               456                     091               13-01-2000        6
7        FFFFFF              456                     NULL              16-01-2000        7
9        FFFFFF              888                     NULL              6-01-2000         7

There are some duplicates for hash_key2. For each duplicate hash_key2, the hash_key1 = FFFFFF and business_key is NULL.
I want to create a new cte after this that discards the hash_key2 duplicates where hash_key 1 = FFFFF and business_key is NULL and hash_key 2 is duplicated. How can I achieve this?
This is how I am collecting information about the duplicate hash_key2 first:
SELECT h_application_2
  FROM h_pit
  GROUP BY h_application_2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Note that there might be cases where
hash_key1 = FFFFFF and business_key is NULL
but the hash_key2 is not a duplicate so i don't want to delete those

Can you try: select * from h_pit where id not in (   select a.id   from h_pit a   left join h_pit b   on a.hash_key2 = b.hash_key2 and a.hash_key1 = 'FFFFFF' and a.business_key is null )?

See example
select t1.*
from h_pit t1
left join h_pit t2 on t1.hash_key2=t2.hash_key2
  and t1.hash_key1='FFFFFF' and t1.business_key is null
  and t2.hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and t2.business_key is not null
where t2.id is null

JOIN result before filter (WHERE)



id
hash_key1
hash_key2
business_key
date
value
id
hash_key1
hash_key2
business_key
date
value




1
12233
234
123
2000-01-12
5
null
null
null
null
null
null


3
33333
456
091
2000-01-13
6
null
null
null
null
null
null


7
FFFFFF
456
null
2000-01-16
7
3
33333
456
091
2000-01-13
6


9
FFFFFF
888
null
2000-01-06
7
null
null
null
null
null




JOIN condition
t1.hash_key2=t2.hash_key2
  and t1.hash_key1='FFFFFF' and t1.business_key is null

is true for left table (t1) rows  - candidates for removing by filter.
Condition
and t2.hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and t2.business_key is not null

select rows from right table(t2) - main row for hash_key2.
If join conditions (all) left join is successful, then t2.id is not null - row can be removed.
Another example
select *
from h_pit t1
where  (t1.hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and t1.business_key is not null)
 or 
  not exists (
    select id from h_pit t2 where t1.hash_key2=t2.hash_key2
  and t2.hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and t2.business_key is not null
)


There we directly take rows
(t1.hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and t1.business_key is not null)

and also take other rows, where not exists row with the same hash_key2 and where (hash_key1<>'FFFFFF' and business_key is not null)
Example.
We do not consider case where hash_key1='FFFFFF' and business_key is not null.

Can you explain this a bit in words as well?
